# Correct return-type of component returning a wrapped component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently trying to write a little wrapper-component in `React` using `TypeScript`. This is my Wrapper:

```
function ConditionalWrapper({ condition, wrapper, children }: { condition?: boolean, wrapper?: (children: React.ReactNode) => any, children?: React.ReactNode }) {
    return condition ? wrapper(children) : children;
}
```

which then can be used like

```
<ConditionalWrapper condition={renderInputGroup} wrapper={c => <InputGroup >{c}</InputGroup>} >
    ...
</ConditionalWrapper>
```

The problem is, that I cannot determine, what the correct return-type of the wrapper-function should be. With the current implementation I could write

```
<ConditionalWrapper condition={renderInputGroup} wrapper={c => "test"} >
    ...
</ConditionalWrapper>
```

which would not throw me an error, as of `any` is not wrong here. But it should be wrong, because I only want another component to be returned.

I already tried `React.ReactNode`, `JSX.Element`, `React.Component`, `React.FunctionComponent` and so on, but nothing has worked so far.

So what would be the correct return-type in order to get an error when returning a `string` instead of a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wrapper` parameter is basically a functional component so it needs to return a value of type `ReactElement | null` which is the same type that a functional component returns.

```js
wrapper?: (children: React.ReactNode) => ReactElement | null
```

Additionally, as the `ConditionalWrapper` function body is currently written TypeScript will give you an error because `wrapper` is marked as optional which means you aren't guaranteed to be able to call the method. You should update the body of the function to check that `wrapper` is provided before calling it. I.E.

```js
return <>{condition && wrapper ? wrapper(children) : children}</>;
```

Comment: Actually this is not working. I got error in implementation `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature` as well as when in use `Type '(c: any) => Element' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>': type, props, key`

Comment: When changing the signature to `wrapper: (children: React.ReactNode) => React.ReactElement | null` I got the error that `type`, `props` and `key` are missing as they are mandatory in `ReactElement`

Comment: Need to update your return statement to wrap the result of the ternary in a fragment. See my updated answer